# rss feed displaying a login screen instead of the page (thunderbird & gitlab)

Tags: thunderbird, rss, gitlab

Using thunderbird 31, I've subscribed to a rss feed to a local gitlab 6.8.1 repo.

The feed is being updated OK, but instead of showing the commit page, it stuck displaying the gitlab login page.

I've tried saving my gitlab creds in Thunderbird.  I have Thunderbird configured to allow cookies from the gitlab machine.

Does anyone have any troubleshooting tips or suggestions as to why a feed might get stuck at the login screen ?